# Automated blaming for broken build in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins

Our build process involves Git, Gerrit and Jenkins. If a Jenkins build is broken, someone has to analyse the latest commits and assign the task of fixing to the individual committers. All developers with commits since the last stable build also get an e-mail, but that simply states "build is broken".

With some machine learning, it seems it should be possible to find the committer "most likely" to have caused a test failure. Say I have two commits since the last stable build

```
Commit abcdef by Bob
Working on database reset logic
awesome-project/src/main/java/com/foobar/database/Reset.java
awesome-project/src/test/java/com/foobar/database/ResetTest.java

Commit abcdef by Fred
Add new VAT codes for Delaware
awesome-project/src/main/java/com/foobar/finance/VatTable.java
awesome-project/src/main/java/com/foobar/finance/VatLogicForDelawreImpl.java
awesome-project/src/test/java/com/foobar/statescenarios/DelawareTest.java
```

And now there's a build failure

```
Stacktrace
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <6> but was <7>
at com.foobar.finance.VatTableTest()
```

Is there a plugin out there that will blame Fred for not having updated the VatTableTest after adding a new VAT row for Delaware? From that stacktrace classes, error message combined with commit message and commited files, it seems that should be possible (I'd gladly accept a "the following failures could not be assigned to a specific commit")

Thanks, Simon

Comment: Prevention is better than cure. Merge request builds solves this problem with gitlab / github. You build, run tests before merging. Don't know how it works in Gerrit. Do you use gerrit for code review and can change sets be built separately.

Comment: Machine learning to predict which commit broke the build?  Come on.  Can't you just script up a `git bisect` session to locate the first commit that won't build and assume that commit's author is where research should start?

Comment: @Vishwanath, we have gerrit build verification in place. There are still plenty of build steps after merging which can and do fail. UI tests are a hot spot.

Comment: @mark-adelsberger, I'm sure I could patch something together, but it will likely not be as good as an established plugin, if there is one. "Machine learing" might be a mis-use of that term, some straight-forward regexp logic would probably suffice

Comment: Yeah, the established functionality for finding the specific commit that broke something (like the build) is `bisect`... that being there, why would someone write a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

For now, we're going with the Email-ext plugin and it's options to send:

- Culprits (ie all committers on the changelog since the last success build)
- Suspects causing the build to begin failing (ie committers on the changelog of the first broken build)